How to move the edge along surface of an angled face?
I want to move this edge along the surface of an angled face. Is it possible?


Select a face of your mesh and in the Transform Orientations panel, create a new orientation, it will be selected by default:

Select the edge you want to move and move it on the desired axis (Y for me):


That works. Thanks.
